# How do I typecast a debounced computed setter in Vue2?

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, computed-properties, debouncing

Vue: `2.6.11`
Typescript: `3.9.3`
Codesandbox: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-blackwell-iknjn?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue).

Here's a simplfied version of what I'm trying to do:

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="computedValue" type="number">
</template>
<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import { debounce } from 'lodash-es';

  export default Vue.extend({
    name: 'MyInput',
    props: {
      value: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      computedValue: {
        get(): number {
          return this.value;
        },
        set: debounce(function(value) {
          this.$emit('update:value', value);
        }, 500)
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

This gets used by parent as `<my-input :value.sync="someProp" />`. It's part of a more complex form system with different types of inputs, configuration driven. But that's irrelevant for the problem I'm presenting. Everything works as expected when I'm not debouncing. As in, everything is typed and inferred correctly.

My problem is I don't know how to tell Typescript to cast the outer `this` onto the debounced function's this, which is something `debounce` does, under the hood.

The actual typescript error is:

```
TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

[image: error screenshot]

The code works (the computed setter is debounced), but Typescript complains about not knowing  what `this`  is inside the debounced function.
If I change the debounced function from a normal function to an arrow function, Typescript no longer barks at me (it now knows what `this` is), but the code stops working.

Does anyone know how to properly cast the value of `this` inside the debounced function?

Note: don't suggest placing `/* @ts-ignore */` one line above. That's what I'm currently doing.

Another note: My guess is I have to override the type the definition of `debounce`, which is currently coming from `@types/lodash-es`, but I still don't know what to replace it with.

Comment: im unfamiliar with typescript syntax in Vue; however I do use the debounce function exactly as you do (using `function(){...}`) which works perfectly in regular Vue. I personally wouldnt be bothered by that `ts-ignore` line

Comment: I started getting bothered about it when my setter has 3 or more occurrences of `this`. Now I need `3 × /* @ts-ignore */`.

Comment: oh apparently its an open issue in typescript, you cant ignore a codeblock atm, only per line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit - caveat:**
>
> It is worth noting that, as Michal Levý has mentioned in the other answer, using `debounced` in a computed setter directly is **definitely not recommended** for the reasons mentioned in his answer - the debounced function should exist *per instance*, or some weird behaviour is bound to emerge. That being said, this answer still stands as a way to add a nicer `this` to functions-as-arguments in the configuration object

*TLDR: The short answer is you can't, not without going to too many hoops for it to be worth it. But you can type `this` as `Vue` which is the next best thing and useful for 99% of the cases.*

The problem lies with Typescript and Type inference: Vue typings use [ThisType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypetype) to inject context into the various methods defined in the configuration objects ([see the source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/e7baaa12055231c9367fa1c7bf917e534bd8a739/types/options.d.ts#L53)) this works fine for functions defined in-place, but using `debounce` means that the function you pass is not part of this process - it's just an argument to `debounce` itself, so TS doesn't know to inject anything to it.

The easiest solution I know of is to inject `Vue` back into the function. See [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#declaring-this-in-a-function) for more info, but the gist is this: passing a `this` argument in the typing works as context-typing (since `this` is a reserved word anyway), so this is valid Typescript:

```
    computedValue: {
      get(): number {
        return this.value;
      },
      set: debounce(function (this: Vue, value: number) {
        this.$emit('update:value', value);
      }, 500),
    },
```

**The good**: it gives you all the Vue typings
**The bad**: no actual context unless you define everything by hand:

```js
set: debounce(function (this: CombinedVueInstance<...>, value: number) {
```

But if you need to do this, using `debounce` directly in a computed setter stops being useful (easier to set the debounced function in `created` as mentioned in another answer).

---

Edit by OP: I think it's important to share (for future users having a similar issue) the more elegant solution Tiago came up with, (as the discussion continued, outside of SO). It's featured inside [MyInput.vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-platform-5dx42?file=/src/components/MyInput.vue)
component of the sandbox we used as playground.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` in anonymous functions is always tricky as the value of `this` depends on how exactly the function will be called. Lodash probably does a right thing here taking care of `this` explicitly but TS can not know that.

Easiest way around it usually "capturing" value of `this` in local variable like this:

```js
methods: {
  someMethod() {
    const self = this
    setTimeout(function() { self.doSomething() }, 500)
  }
}
```

This is of course not possible with your code **BUT** I think there is one more problem with your code and it is the way how you create your debouncing wrapper. It is [hinted](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#debouncing-and-throttling) in Vue 3 documentation but applies to Vue 2 too

> this approach is potentially problematic for components that are reused because they'll all share the same debounced function.

To fix that (and at the same time fix the TS problem):

```js
computed: {
      computedValue: {
        get(): number {
          return this.value;
        },
        set(value): void {
          this.debouncedSetter(value)
        }
      }
    },
created() {
  self = this
  this.debouncedSetter = debounce(function(value) {
    self.$emit('update:value', value);
  }, 500)
}
```

Comment: I agree your proposed solution would work, but I personally consider it a hack. Besides, it's a hack needed for TypeScript, not for JavaScript. Which, in my mind, contradicts with Typescript's role in development. Using Typescript, at least in principle, should have a `null` footprint on the JavaScript output and what you're suggesting is changing JS to please TS. I find using `/* ts-ignore */` a more conceptually correct solution in this case (unless there's a way to actually tell TypeScript what `debounce` does, without having to create multiple copies of `debounce` or of `this`).

Comment: But your code is incorrect on JS level. Unless of course you want to share **one** debounced wrapper between all instances of your component

Comment: Having the debounce wrapper shared across multiple instances of the component is a different problem, not what I'm asking about. And it doesn't change the fact Typescript doesn't work as expected inside the debounced function. It only works correctly if I make the function an arrow function, which, in JavaScript, makes it no longer perform correctly. Please note I've added a codesanbox featuring the problem.